# 403 Forbidden: AWS S3, Django, S3Boto3Storage, CKEditor

Tags: django, amazon-s3, ckeditor, boto3, pythonanywhere

After several days of continuous attempts, I'm nearly ready to give up. I have a popular setup and I see many people have similar issues, but there is no comprehensive (and working!) answer.

I get this sort of errors in browser:

> GET
> https://hull2hull-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ckeditor/ckeditor/?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVIMQUGHJHHUVNIPN&Signature=LDq%2F5bhKJUUIUIUUO3GGoH0Iksoho%3D&Expires=1618438498lang/en.js&t=K5H9
> net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

My website is powered by Django and hosted on Pythonanywhere. Static files are on Amazon S3 with a private policy. I connect Django and S3 bucket with S3Boto3Storage. Most of my static files (picture library, admin files etc) are working fine, but not when it comes to some js files or specific components. Particularly CKEditor and Debug Toolbar are refusing to work.

What I tried:

- make my bucket public - FAILED (but maybe did it wrong somehow? how can I check the effect?)
- edit CORS - FAILED (I had some CORS errors initially, those were fixed)

My current CORS:

> [
> {
> "AllowedHeaders": [
> "*"
> ],
> "AllowedMethods": [
> "HEAD",
> "GET"
> ],
> "AllowedOrigins": [
> "https://hull2hull-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
> "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
> "http://127.0.0.1",
> "http://localhost",
> "http://localhost:8000"
> ],
> "ExposeHeaders": []
> } ]

- change policy - FAILED

My current policy:

> {
> "Version": "2012-10-17",
> "Statement": [
> {
> "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
> "Effect": "Allow",
> "Principal": "*",
> "Action": "s3:GetObject",
> "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::hull2hull-bucket/*"
> }
> ] }

- install corsheaders - FAILED (again, maybe helped with some CORS errors initially)

I really don't know what else is left to do. I believe I have quite popular setup for a website,  there are tons of similar questions everywhere, and yet - no answer :(

Comment: If a file doesn't exist, S3 will throw a 403 - Have you confirmed that the files are actually in the path that it's trying to load?

Comment: I think in this case it will throw another error, 404 or smth. And no, files are in place.

Comment: No, if files don't exist, you'll see 403. If you add all your related settings, that would be helpful.

Comment: I think the below should cover all relevant settings in Django. I did check the presence of files in AWS - it's all there. SO it must be some access issue.

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'storages',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = (
  'http://localhost:8000',
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
  'https://www.hull2hull.com'
)`

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***********'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***********'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'hull2hull-bucket'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True`

Comment: @DmitryKhavanskiy did you solved?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in a similar situation in my django project (I've used IBM storage for the object storage instead) and after hours of frustration and headbanging I seem to have found the cause of the situation here.

It is important to understand that IBM object storage, as well as amazon s3 storage are flat i.e., they don't have the typical concept of files and directories. Instead all the files are located in a single location with directory location as file name prefix.
See for more [info][1]:

Now with that knowledge, if you take a look at the html rendered from the html rendered upon adding the model you'll notice that the script tag used to fetch the javascript for ckeditor has something interesting.

```
<script src="{ENDPOINT_URL}/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js?AWSAccessKeyId={ACCESS_ID};" data-ckeditor-basepath="{ENDPOINT_URL}/ckeditor/ckeditor/?AWSAccessKeyId={ACCESS_ID};" id="ckeditor-init-script"></script>
```

Now if you notice within the script there is a data-ckeditor-basepath location. This is most likely the directory within which all the ckeditor related modules files are stored. However, in our case the operation of fetching this is not defined in itself. The reason being that the concept of directory and folder doesn't exist for s3 storages.
As far as I understand, this is an error within the editor implementation and cannot be gotten rid of. However, a makeshift workaround is that you can manually add the script tag for the required js while getting rid of the "data-ckeditor-basepath" attribute.

```
<script src="{ENDPOINT_URL}/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js?AWSAccessKeyId={ACCESS_ID};" id="ckeditor-init-script"></script>
```

I would suggest adding it in the base.html template within django module. You can find it in the following location (within your virtual environment):

"\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html".

You can add it just before the extra headers are loaded in the extrahead block.

```
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
```

It is important to remember that this is just a makeshift solution and not a permanent one. The basepath attribute is most likely used somewhere but I'm just not able to figure out where. Since, so far, I've been able to use ckeditor without any issues.
Do remember that it's best not to use any editor which might be formatting the file automatically with addons (i.e. pylint). I edited it with notepad and I'd suggest that to you too.

It's best to add the tag only within a virtual environment for the project.
Further, it might be possible to change the header in the tag template itself but I just went with whatever I could do.

Also I believe that it'd be necessary to ensure public access as well since it'll be needed whenever any resources are rendered from within the used modules. (But that's just my opinion and I am not too sure about that myself).

Comment: can you elaborate that where we need to add the script tag for `ckeditor`, I have deployed my project using `docker-compose` . Do we need to add it inside our own `base` template or the `ckedior` moduel's base template or the `Django admin` template?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with docker but, in case you're facing the above situation on a similar setup i.e. AWS S3, Django, S3Boto3Storage, CKEditor, and using a public cloud storage is an option, I would suggest to first disable AWS_AUTHSTRING in your settings.py.  If that doesn't work, you can try to override the default django admin template by locating a file with similar name in your templates folder within a subfolder named admin. I overwrote the base_site.html template by copying the contents with my custom script tag in templates/admin/base_site.html .

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite straightforward, which is why you should refer to documentation when having issues with any particular library.

1. `django-ckeditor` will not work with S3 through `django-storages` without this line in `settings.py`:

   `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False`

> ref: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#using-s3

2. `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` (optional; default is `True`)
   Setting `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` to `False` to remove query parameter authentication from generated URLs. This can be useful if your S3 buckets are public.

> ref:
> https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Answer (score 1):

I did the above suggestions but didn't work for me.
CKEditor by default uses the static directory to reference the static files. When I deployed my app with Nginx, the static_root used *staticfiles* to *collectstatic*. By the way, this is digitalocean, but you can always provide the full path to your directory on your cloud provider.
A hack that worked for me was to have the below configuration in my settings file.

```py
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
CKEDITOR_BROWSE_SHOW_DIRS = True
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_DATE = False
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/<bucket_name>/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
```

The ***CKEDITOR_BASEPATH*** worked when I specified the full path.
Hope it helps.

Comment: it works for me, thanks!, I use this solution (only **CKEDITOR_BASEPATH**) since I'm using a different storage package like [https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage](django_s3_storage) a fork for django-storages but focused only on AWS3 handling